# Nested pattern matching not exhaustive warning

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

Consider the following code example:

```
function
  | [] -> "bla"
  | ds -> let x::l = List.rev ds in "woot";;
```

When compiling / interpreting the above piece of code the following warning occur:

```
line 3, characters 14-18:
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a case that is not matched:
[]
```

I wonder why this warning appear. It is clear that [] is not a valid option due to the top level pattern-matching. I expect the compiler / interpreter of OCaml to be able to easily deduce the exhaustiveness of the above code by passing information from the top-level matching to the nested matching. Why isn't that the case? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml is complaining about

```
let x::l = List.rev ds in "woot"
```

which will fail if `List.rev ds` produces `[]`.

Of course, we know that it can't, because if `List.rev ds` would be empty, then `ds` would have to be empty, which is impossible because of the other guard; but OCaml doesn't know that.

See [docs](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/common_error_messages.html#This-pattern-matching-is-not-exhaustive):

> OCaml's pattern matching can check whether a set of patterns is exhaustive or not, based on the *type* only.

and goes on to present an example that is remarkably similar to yours.

Regarding your "easily deduce the exhaustiveness of the above code"... I don't think it's as easy as you make it sound. Imagine if you demanded instead of `ds` not being empty that it must be "foo", and the inner guard making sure that `Digest.to_hex(Digest.string ds)` is `"acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8"` (which *must* be so, as that is the MD5 digest of `"foo"`). Not as simple any more, even for us humans. But is there a difference between `List.rev ds` and `Digest.to_hex(Digest.string ds)`, from a computer's point of view? Types are easy. Values are *hard*.

Comment: There is a difference between the examples in your answer and my question. In both of your examples, the information can be obtained only when evaluating the expressions. In my case, [ ] is just a type constructor (specifically, the base case of the inductive list type), this being exactly the kind of information useful to the type inference system.

Comment: Fair. Maybe it is not _as_ hard. It is still hard enough for OCaml devs to not want to bother with, as the quote shows. Constructors are not types, and OCaml can’t deal. If you proposed a patch that could do what you want, I’m sure they’d be happy to discuss integrating it.